# jQuery and Cookies plugin - Can't get cookie for AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm writing a script using Tampermonkey (Greasemonkey in FF), and I need to send POST request back to server (using GM_xmlhttpRequest) and in the parameter it sends some cookies too. But here's the problem, when I want to get some of these cookies (using Cookies plugin), they are undefined (some are defined, some not) even though it sends them in the parameter. How is that possible? And how to get them?
EDIT: Just to be clear, when I want to use:

```
alert(cookie);
```

To just find out if they have value, is says that they are undefined, but in parameter they have a value.
Thanks.

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but can I find out the header of that cookie?

Comment: It says HTTP/1.1 if it is what you meant.

Comment: In the header of response, there is nothing like "HTTP-only": http://imgur.com/a/KXBkg

Comment: K, so that may not be the issue then.